Проблема в приложении React, react-router
Всем привет. В небольшом проекте есть пару багов, не могу поправить.
Используется роутер 5.3.0, т.к. по видосам там был 5, поэтому использовал его. Это первый проект с ним.
Если в приложении открыть статью любую НЕ на первой странице, то при перемещении назад из неё всегда возвращает на первую стр блога. Пробовал сохранять значение currentPage и передавать, не срабатывает, через useHistory и useLocation пробовал что-то. Не совсем понимаю пока.
https://github.com/gwynbleidd102/blog/blob/master/src/components/blogList/blogList.jsx
И такой момент, если открыть чужую статью и в урле напрямую поменять путь на edit-article, откроется форма редактирования. Отредачить чужую статью нельзя, т.к. сервер не даст, но интересно как при прямом изменении урла не для своей статьи, делать редирект на главную, к примеру. Понимаю, что надо сделать что-то проверки на юзера, но честно я запутался просто.
https://github.com/gwynbleidd102/blog/blob/master/src/components/article/article.jsx
Вот тут форма создания/редактирования, писал условие ещё одно в нём, не знаю какое второе условие лучше указать:
if (formTitle === 'Edit article') {
  return <Redirect to="/" />
}

В целом проект довольно колхозно написан, пишу для себя. Спасибо.

Видимо какой-то древний туториал, раз используется простой redux. Все давно перешли на тулкит. Чей видос? Есть в открытом доступе?
